# Destroying session on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, destroy

I need to finish a session in a Wordpress using `session_destroy()` and it's not working.

In the **index.php** I have

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

And at **logout.php** I have

```
<?php session_destroy(); header('Location: http://mysite.stack.br');?>
```

But the session never finish. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions (stateless). You will need to look up in the Wordpress documentation how to do the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
<?php

$yourSession= WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance(get_current_user_id());
$yourSession->destroy_all();
```